# Adding new nodes to an SVG <use> tag

Tags: svg

Just playing the defs and use for the first time. What I would like to do is use defs to build a base template and then when I use it customise it by adding some more inner tags.

Is this possible, as when I try to do it in Firefox it doesn't render any tags which I place as children to the use tag. e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="10000px" height="5500px" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <defs>
        <g id="storyCard">
            <rect width="800px" height="500px" fill="#ffff00" />
            <path d="M 20 120 L 780 120 M 640 20 L 640 120" stroke-width="6px" stroke="black" fill="none" />
        </g>
    </defs>

    <!-- White Board -->
    <path d="M 0 0 L 10000 0 L 10000 550 L 0 5500 z M 2000 0 L 2000 5500" stroke-width="20px" stroke="black" fill="none" />
    <use xlink:href="#storyCard" transform="translate(100,100)" />
    <use xlink:href="#storyCard" transform="translate(1000,200)" >
            <text x="20" y="80" font-size="45" font-weight="bold" font-family="Comic Sans MS, cursive">
                My Dummy Story
            </text>
    </use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't directly possible with use. The [use element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) can contain description and animation elements, but it doesn't behave like an [XBL](http://www.w3.org/TR/xbl/) container.

You could use XBL, if you're targeting firefox.

To stay within SVG, make a group and use the background:

```
    <g transform="translate(1000,200)" >
        <use xlink:href="#storyCard"/>
        <text x="20" y="80" font-size="45" font-weight="bold" font-family="Comic Sans MS, cursive">
            My Dummy Story
        </text>
    </g>
```